# Custom fill formula in Excel

Tags: excel-2013

I'm trying to take information from one sheet called `DRAW` and take it to another sheet.

On the draw sheet it's in a column and on the new sheet I want in in a row.

I want it to show what ever is in the Draw sheet cell.

My formula is `=DRAW!B254`

Problem:
But when I go to auto fill across the row it changes the column letter to E254 and I want it to go B255, B256 etc.

I have tried to use the `$` to anchor it but it anchors the whole cell not just the column letter.

Any ideas? I have over 30 sheets to fill and I loathe to do it all manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to use the *Copy > PaseteSpecial Transpose* so try this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(IT$1),2,4,1,"DRAW"))
```

Enter it in any column. Then auto fill.

**Edit1:**
`Column(IT$1)` returns *254*
`Address(254,2,4,1,"DRAW")` returns `DRAW!B254` in the form of text.
`Indirect` then accepts this string and convert it to actual reference.
When you autofill to the left as you've described, `Column(IT$1)` changes value because column is relative.

Comment: I have tried to transpose but I have merged cells and it doesn't want to play ball with me. How does this one work?

Comment: Does it work for you? Btw, Indirect accepts string addresses and returns it as the actual cell reference. We use Address to swap the column and row reference.